# Why I get this error when the SQL grammar is well and id column doesn't exists there?

Tags: mysql

I execute the following query:

```
SELECT groupName, groupId 
FROM registrations 
WHERE eventId = 34 
  AND groupId IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY groupId
```

I verified it and is well, and the strange thing is the exception: Column 'id' not found. That column doesn't exists anywhere.

```
{"content":"Unhandled Server Exception: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT groupName, groupId FROM registrations WHERE eventId = 34 AND groupId IS NOT NULL GROUP BY groupId]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found."}
```

Comment: @MichaelO I runned the query in the workbench and it works!

Comment: Could you not simply do `SELECT DISTINCT groupName, groupId 
FROM registrations 
WHERE eventId = 34 
  AND groupId IS NOT NULL`

Comment: You are using invalid SQL.. SELECT groupName, groupId .... GROUP BY groupId  will give you bad results on MySQL server.... read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have an incorrect mapping on your entity object. Check the corresponding Java class (probably called RegistrationEntity). Ensure that all of the field names correspond to your table names; it sounds like you have a field called id when it needs to be called groupId (or eventId). If you are using the @Column annotation with a name argument, make sure these match your column names as well.